# Issue with Map.update Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
type Cxt = Map Id (Addr, Type)
data St = St
    { cotxt           :: [Cxt]   -- ^ Context. }


temp <- gets cotxt
case temp of
  [currentCxt] -> modify $ \ st -> st {cotxt = [Map.update (\x -> if x == Nothing then Nothing else Just (addr2,typ2)) id  currentCxt]}
  (currentCxt:cxts) -> modify $ \ st -> st {cotxt = Map.update (\x -> if x == Nothing then Nothing else Just (addr2,typ2)) id currentCxt:cxts}
```

I am unable to find the issue as I followed the procedure from here https://caiorss.github.io/Functional-Programming/haskell/data_map.html

Errors at line [currentCxt] & similar errors for the other line as well

```
1.  • Couldn't match type ‘Maybe a0’ with ‘(Addr, Type)’
      Expected type: [Cxt]
        Actual type: [Map Id (Maybe a0)]
2. • Couldn't match type ‘(Addr, Type)’ with ‘Maybe a0’
      Expected type: Maybe (Maybe a0)
        Actual type: Maybe (Addr, Type)
    • In the expression: Just (addr2, typ2)
      In the expression:
        if x == Nothing then Nothing else Just (addr2, typ2)
      In the first argument of ‘Map.update’, namely
        ‘(\ x -> if x == Nothing then Nothing else Just (addr2, typ2))’

3.  • Couldn't match type ‘(Addr, Type)’ with ‘Maybe a0’
      Expected type: Map Id (Maybe a0)
        Actual type: Cxt
```

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, of course, but the first line of your pattern match (`[currentCtx] -> ...`) is completely redundant: the second pattern will also match single-element lists, and the second match's RHS also behaves exactly the same way as the first match's RHS when specialized to `cxts = []`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `Map.update` takes a function `(Addr, Type) -> Maybe (Addr, Type)` as it's first argument, but the function you're supplying:

```
\x -> if x == Nothing then Nothing else Just (addr2,type2)
```

looks like it's of type:

```
Maybe (Addr, Type) -> Maybe (Addr, Type)
```

That seems to be the main problem.  Maybe you meant `Map.alter` in place of `Map.update`?  Though, if you want to unconditionally replace the item at key `id` with `(addr2,typ2)`, then:

```
Map.insert id (addr2,typ2) currentCtx
```

is more straightforward.

Also, as a stylistic note, using `id` as an identifier in Haskell for anything other than the built-in identity function will be very confusing to other Haskell programmers.